# Nested serialization for JSON

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to return a JSON like this after a successful post request.

```
{
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "ports": [
        {port: "", service: ""}
    ],
    "first_scan": "date",
    "last_updated": "date"
}
```

I'm trying to make my serializer so that whenever my nmap function which returns data in this way on the console:

```
Host : 127.0.0.1 (localhost) State : up
port : 631      service : CUPS
port : 902      service : VMware Authentication Daemon
port : 6463     service : 
port : 8000     service : WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.3
```

It would parse it like the JSON mentioned.

I have tried making a model like this in my `models.py`

```
class nmapScan(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)
    ports = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    service = models.TextField()
    first_scan = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['first_scan']
```

But I'm still confused by this nested serialization concept. How would I go on making the data get parsed from my function, return it like that certain JSON and have it stored in the database (assuming my model is right) properly?

Comment: what kind of object holds these data in the program? dict ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending your DB, you can you use something like this:

```
class nmapScan(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)
    services = JSONField()              # [{"service": "", "port": ""}, ... ]
    first_scan = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['first_scan']

#####################

scan = nmapScan.objects.get(...)
for service in scan.services:
    service['port']
    service['name']
```

Or

```
class nmapScan(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)

    first_scan = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['first_scan']


class Service(models.Model):
    port = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    name = models.TextField()              # service name
    scan = ForeignKey(nmapScan, related_name='services')

#####################

scan = nmapScan.objects.get(...)
for service in scan.services.all():
    service.port
    service.name
```